# retrieving a lot of data from api and use it inside UICollectionView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, api, uicollectionview

Hello I am working on an app that retrieves data about movies but I have some problems here is my code:

```
let categories = [MovieCategory(generID: "28", categoryTitle: "Action")
    ,MovieCategory(generID: "16", categoryTitle: "Animation")
    ,MovieCategory(generID: "35", categoryTitle: "Comedy"),
     MovieCategory(generID: "18", categoryTitle: "Drama"),
     MovieCategory(generID: "27", categoryTitle: "Horror"),
     MovieCategory(generID: "10752", categoryTitle: "War")]

func parseJson( category: MovieCategory)
{

    self.collectionView.reloadData()
    var currentCategory = category
    let parameters = ["api_key":"8460d476d21be7e26a99234d8ca8de51","sort_by":"false","include_video":"false","with_genres":category.generID]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (response) in
        if response.result.isSuccess{
            let movieJSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

for i in 0..<20{
        let title = movieJSON["results"][i]["title"].stringValue
        let posterPath = movieJSON["results"][i]["poster_path"].stringValue

        let overview = movieJSON["results"][i]["overview"].stringValue
        let dateReleased = movieJSON["results"][i]["release_date"].stringValue
        let voteAverage = movieJSON["results"][i]["vote_average"].stringValue
        if let safeImage = self.createImage(posterPath: posterPath)
        {
        let movieDetails = MovieDetails(movieTitle: title, poster: safeImage, voteAverage: voteAverage, overview: overview, releaseDate: dateReleased)
        currentCategory.categoryMovies.append(movieDetails)
        self.actionMovies.append(UIImage(named: "gul")!)
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }

            }

                                   }

        }
}
```

and I use two structs as data sources and there they are:

```
struct MovieCategory {
let generID:String
let categoryTitle:String
var categoryMovies:[MovieDetails] = []
```

}
and:

```
struct MovieDetails{
let movieTitle:String
let poster:UIImage
let voteAverage:String
let overview:String
let releaseDate:String
```

} 
but when I want to get the data inside category.categoryMovies it turns out to be empty how ever I am appending data to it in parseJson function I don't know why it is empty when numberOfItemsInSection method is called it returns categories[section].categoryMovies.count and it doesn't call cellForItemAtIndexpath method that makes me think it is empty .
if you know the solution I really appreciate your help.

thank you

Comment: Could you show snippets of your resource fetching code.

Comment: You probably need to think about this a different way.  You can't know how long it will take to download something, but you do know when the something is downloaded.  You will probably find it easier to use something like SDWebImage or Kingfisher to download the images.  They have convenience methods that can put a placeholder image into an image view and replace it when the download is complete.

Comment: If you don't want to use external code then you will need to implement something similar yourself; check your image cache to see if the image is available.  If not, start the download and pass a closure that will update the image view when the download is complete

Comment: `URLSessionDownloadDelegate` will be your best friend in this case. What's happening, most likely, is that your view is loading before your data is downloaded. If you use a download delegate you can track your download progress and fire the view updates when the download is completed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution just define the structs as class because they pass the values by reference and it solves my problem